# How can you evaluate a PropertyPath against an object *without* using a binding? (i.e. what does a binding itself use?)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

> Note: To those who voted to close this. There's a specific reason I added the note.  The solutions found here offer up using a binding against a dummy object/property, but as I specifically called out, I am not looking for a solution that uses binding. I'm trying to utilize/uncover the *existing* mechanism that bindings use without re-inventing the wheel.  That's why I posted this with that note calling out that this is not in fact a duplicate. I have now edited the title to clarify this.

When applying a `binding`, you're essentially saying 'bind property path 'x' of source object 'a' to property path 'y' of target object 'b''. The binding itself specifies a source and a PropertyPath.  It is then 'bound' to the target object's property.

However, I'm trying to evaluate the path directly against a source object and storing that in a variable.

***Note: Yes I know I can create a dummy target class with a property of type Object and bind to that, then inspect it for a value, as several other answers here on StackOverflow and elsewhere say (see [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42272) for that solution), but I'm trying to avoid binding altogether. I'm looking for what the binding class does internally with the source and path.***

```
var sourceObject = new Foo();
var propertyPath = new PropertyPath("Some.Property.Relative.To.Foo");

// What is equivalent to 'var pathValue = sourceObject.Some.Property.Relative.To.Foo;'
var pathValue = ???
```

Comment: When you create a binding, is not it mean, that you know what type of value and possible values can be there? Maybe I do not understood something...

Comment: I re-worded the question and added a code snippet to better explain what I'm after.

Comment: In .net sources it's eval property that will be used for binding, I suppose, that it's final step, because we can set string path interpretation in few different ways sometimes, or, if it only one way, it's not so big problem to recover path when you now target object and property name.

Comment: @RichardSchneider, as I specifically called out in my question, this is not a duplicate because that solution is not what I'm asking.  Please read the question before simply marking it as such.  It's really frustrating to take the time to write something out only to have it ignored.

Comment: @Spawn, I'm not sure what you mean in your comment. Can you please instead put it as an answer with a source code example?

Comment: Are you asking how WPF internally evaluates the binding?

Comment: I'm asking how canny leverage the same mechanism that WPF already does but without having to create a dummy object and new binding.  So in short, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Binding parses the PropertyPath (which is basically just a string) and finds the property and it's value via reflection.

You can do it yourself: simplest method would be to split the path by '.' and search properties by name recursively. But there is also a simple method that does it if you add reference to System.Web: [DataBinder.Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
var pathValue = DataBinder.Eval(sourceObject, propertyPath.Path)
```